# Handling workload changes

Tags: stress, workload

I am seeking advice on how to deal with workload changes. In the past year there have been various changes in the office I work in resulting in the office to be understaffed and with no manager. Since then, there have been a lot of changes in my workload. I was given the responsibility to perform the work of three different positions in the office and that includes work that should be performed by office management. I agreed to the increased workload because I wanted the office to succeed during these difficult times and because I was promised a change in position by senior administration in the company.

However, it has been months since these changes took place and no such position change has occurred. Moreover, the excess workload has resulted in lots stress to the point that it is affecting my overall health. As a result, I am burned out from the excess workload and I am struggling to communicate my problems with the senior administration in the company as there has been limited to no support from administration these past few months.

I would really appreciate any advice to continue facing this situation.

Thanks!

Comment: Is short-term disability an option due to all the stress?

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately when people take on a greater workload, after a while it's sometimes assumed that it's the norm for them. However too late to worry about that now.

You need to go see your boss or bosses and explain that what was a temporary solution is no longer working out and you need to have some changes since you feel you're burning out and it's affecting your health.

When you go in, take a list of your duties before the extra, and a list of what has been added on so that they can easily see the difference, also make a point of showing any extra hours that you work in order to fulfill the extra duties.. Then you can negotiate from there. But make sure you have the lists, because without them it would just look like you're vaguely looking for a pay rise or something. You need concrete stuff to show.